# What happens to my German residence permit if I renounce my citizenship? Would it affect my ability to get permanent residence later on?

Tags: germany, residence-cards

If I renounce my citizenship for my home country (to become stateless person) while having a residence permit from Germany that I applied using my passport from the very same country, would my residence permit cancelled, or would it prevent me from getting a permanent residence in Germany later on?

Comment: Does your country allow its citizens to renounce their nationality without having acquired another?

Comment: @Traveller yes it does

Comment: Our you sure? The main goal of the 1961 [Convention on the Reduction of Statelessnes](https://www.unhcr.org/ibelong/wp-content/uploads/1961-Convention-on-the-reduction-of-Statelessness_ENG.pdf) is to **avoid** someone becoming stateless. I would be interested in learning which country this is.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it does, provided that you can convince them that you will get a citizenship from another country.

Comment: But in your case you will not be able to do that, since you won't have a **Einbürgerungszusicherung**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I was actually referring to this meaning of "renounciation" : https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21210/renouncing-your-citizenship-but-the-government-doesnt-accept-can-you-still-get

Comment: I have given an answer to that, but it doesn't have anything to do with your present situation where you don't even fullfill the condition of a **permanent residence** (not to mention nationalization).

Comment: @MarkJohnson and which conditions is that I'm not fulfilling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two questions.

Yes, your **residence permit** will become invalid, because a condition (no valid passport) under which the residence permit was issued has changed.

You will also not have a valid passport.

You **must** *immediately apply* for a new residence permit at your responsible **Immigration Office**, during which a **stateless passport** will be issued. Until you receive that passport, travel outside Germany will not be possible.

You must supply all relevant documents (including your present residence permit) leading up to the loss of your present citizenship. When possible, a letter stating that no new passport will be issued by your present country of citizenship should also be presented. Depending on the jurasdiction, the loss of citizenship (through the withdrawal of the passport) may become effective immediately, but only officially confirmed (through a **Certificate of Loss of Nationality**) much later.

**Note**:
For persons within the process of nationalization, the

- **Assurance of citizenship** (**Einbürgerungszusicherung**)

must also be submitted.

---

The conditions for a **permanent residence** are based on the amount of time (with certain exceptions for students) that you, as a person, have legally spent within the country. The change of citizenship will therefore **not affect** the amount of time collected.

---

**Sources**:

- [Travel document - Reissue - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/325471/en/)

  - [§ 4 AufenthV - Einzelnorm](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__4.html) (german only)